# What would cause a SQL query to take significantly different amounts of time to run?

Tags: t-sql

I have a SQL query (that I'm intending to turn into a view). When I run it, it usually takes ~5-10 seconds to run. However, about 1/3 of the time, it takes about 68 seconds to run. What kinds of things could cause this significant variation between these run times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a query needs to create a temporal table, that it will be very slow. This is the case when you combine `JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. Also the use of subqueries is slow.

In your case, however, it looks like the same query takes a lot longer. This is mostly the case when the server / mysql server or the hard drive are under heavy load

Comment: Yep! I checked with the server administrator, and apparently some automated process started in their SQL database that is taking up a significant amount of time/CPU.